# Scroll issue in mootools (In Firefox it's okay but Chrome giving some issue)

Tags: mootools

I have set following code to create a floating navigation menu. It works fine in Firefox but Chrome has some issue. It keep resetting when I manually scroll the bar to it's threshold.

```
    var nav = $$('#navigationBar');
var navCord = nav.getCoordinates();
var navHomeY = navCord[0].top;
var isFixed = false;
var $w = $(window);

$w.addEvent('scroll', function(){

    var scrollTop = $w.getScroll().y;
    console.log(scrollTop + ' and ' + navHomeY);
    var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
    if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed){
        console.log("fix it now");
        nav.setStyles({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0,
            left: navCord[0].left,
            width: navCord[0].width
        });
        isFixed = true;
    }
    else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
    {
        nav.setStyles({
            position: null,
            top: null,
            left: null,
            width: null
        });
        isFixed = false;
    }
});

});
```

Here is the console.log output from Chrome.

```
0 and 25 index.php:532
10 and 25 index.php:532
20 and 25 index.php:532
41 and 25 index.php:532
fix it now index.php:537
0 and 25 index.php:532 (PROBLEM: scrollTop reset happen)
```

Here is the console.log output from Firefox.

```
9 and 25
17 and 25
26 and 25
fix it now
33 and 25
```

In short, in Firefox scrollTop behave nicely and doesn't reset to 0 where as in Chrome it does.

Comment: MooTools 1.2 is 5 years old, can you upgrade to latest 1.5.x? If not can you make a jsFiddle to recreate the problem?

Comment: @Sergio I guess it's mootools 1.4. I selected older tag wrongly.

Comment: Anyone can help ? the working site is at http://www.dvsupplies.com

Comment: Your website still has version 1.2.5.